# Access is denied for some particular file types using Java on Windows 7

Tags: java, windows-7-x64

I have tried the followings for `.txt`, `.sql`, `.java` with success BUT I can't write file with the extension with `.pdf`, `.jpg`, `.zip`.

```
File file = new File("d:/myFolder/something.txt");
File file = new File("d:/myFolder/something.sql");
File file = new File("d:/myFolder/something.java");

// Executed Successfully for the above 3 but java.io.FileNotFoundException (Access is denied) show for these files below.
File file = new File("d:/myFolder/something.jpg");
File file = new File("d:/myFolder/something.pdf");
File file = new File("d:/myFolder/something.zip");

try {
  FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
  fos.write(mpf.getBytes());
  fos.close();
  fos.flush();
} catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Project is being developed using spring MVC on Windows 7 (64 bit).

Comment: Maybe those files already exist? Java doesn't care about the file extension.

Comment: Do you have an unusual antivirus or similar security product running  on your Windows?

Comment: @JoshuaFox Yes,  it is kaspersky under domain

Comment: Could that be the cause?

Comment: Yes, it is dear @JoshuaFox. When I stop anti-virus it works fine. But how can I fix without stopping anti-virus ?

Comment: Since this appears to be part of the answer, now moving from a comment to an answer

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps there is an  unusual antivirus or similar security product running on your Windows?

If so, either disable the antivirus or configure it to permit these filetypes.

So long as it is enabled, it is actually doing exactly what it is supposed to do by blocking these file-writes.

Comment: The central security team of my institution told me that they have allowed all file types. But still not working.

Comment: OK. It seems that you need to inquire  about Kaspersky antivirus in relevant forums. In other  words, the question is not  about Java any more.